# XAML UWP focus background on custom button

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, focus

On a XAML UWP application, Ive a class extending Button. 
I've setted a Background ImageBrush.

My problem is that when my buttons get the focus or on the mouseover event, a grey rectangle bordered with black appear on my button.

I've tried <del>a shitton of</del> many solution, from changing foreground to modifying FocusVisualPrimary/SecondaryBrush on various kind of event (`gotFocus`, `mouseEntered`, `mouseover`). 
Nothing worked, the best result I got was with setting `button.Background = "originalBitmapImage"` on `mouseover` event (I created a new ImageBrush with the same image path as the original background then attributed it to BackGround), but the image is all flickering when mouseover is fired (as it reload a new image each time).

Here is an picture showing the problem (left : normal button, right : same button with mouseover) :

[image: Demo]

I would like to keep the same image in the two case, I'm a bit at loss about how to do this.

```
public class MyButton : Button 
{

private static string Image_path = "ms-appx:///assets/Button.png";

        public MyButton()
        {

            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush()
            {
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(MyButton.Image_path))
            };
            this.Background = brush;

            this.PointerEntered += a;

        }

        // This almost work, but the image is flickering when event is fired
        private void a(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush()
            {
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(MyButton.Image_path))
            };
            //this.Foreground = brush;
            this.Background = brush;
        }
}
```

Comment: If you want to just stop flickering, save these images in some external fields. If you want to prevent this weird behaviour, you could create template, or even easier use ContentControl and set image as content, or Border with it's background property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found a solution : I added style to my 5 types of button to each page of my project. This is not really nice solution as button are created from c# class (code behind) in order to factorises the code, and all style are adding 500+ code line for simple image modification on mouseover....

I used this kind of styling :

'

```
    <Style TargetType="local:MyButton">
        <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />-->
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4" />
        <!--<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />-->
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Page.Resources>'
```

Answer (score 1):

We can copy the default style of the `Button` then we can edit the `PointerOver` of `VisualState` in the `Template`.

From the default style, it set `ButtonBackgroundPointerOver` ThemeResource to the  `Background` of the Button in the `PointerOver` VisualState. So we can define the `ButtonBackgroundPointerOver` in the page's resources that without editing the style of the `Button`.

For example:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBackground" ResourceKey="MyMyImageBrush" />
    <StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" ResourceKey="MyMyImageBrush" />
    <StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPressed" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush" />
    <ImageBrush x:Key="MyMyImageBrush" ImageSource="ms-appx:///assets/Button.png" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Thx, I'll test this solution in a short time. In case, is there any way to do this in code behind ? My button is a class at this moment, not a XAML element.

Comment: It's the best solution I got for this moment but this modify all buttons Ive on the page. Problem is that I can have more than 1 type of button : so Ill need to be able to set a different background (ie different images in my case) for different type of button. If there was a solution wich can be implemented on code behind directly in my different button class it would be quite cool. Thx